# How to hide Widget If not supported by Android API?

Tags: android

I am developing multiple widgets, One of them uses ListView but ListView is not supported by Android 2.3.
So, if my app is installed in Android 2.3 at that time widget with ListView should not display in widget's list.
But my that widget with ListView is showing in widget's list and if i click on it than it shows me Force Closed.

That's why i want to hide Those Widgets from widget's list.
If any one has any suggestions please reply.

It shows me Force Closed and following Error for widget
[image]
 Same widget i run in Android 4.2 then it shows me as per following list
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: "One of them uses ListView but ListView is not supported by Android 2.3" -- `ListView` is most definitely supported in Android 2.3.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am using listview in widget, Please review this link :  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.   //Using App Widgets with Collections

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I am developing multiple widgets

No, you are developing multiple **app widgets**. While I am sorry that the terms are confusing, it is very important for you to use the right terminology in your question.

> One of them uses ListView but ListView is not supported by Android 2.3.

Correct, `ListView` is not supported in **app widgets** in Android 2.3 or lower.

> So, if my app is installed in Android 2.3 at that time widget with ListView should not display in widget's list.

Step #1: Create a `res/values/bools.xml` file, defining a boolean resource, with a name of `is_honeycomb`, and a value of `false`.

Step #2: Create a `res/values-v11/bools.xml` file, defining another boolean resource, with the same name (`is_honeycomb`), and a value of `true`

Step #3: In your manifest, on the `<receiver>` element for the `AppWidgetProvider` that uses a `ListView`, add `android:enabled="@bool/is_honeycomb"`.

The net effect is that on Android 3.0+ devices, your `ListView` app widget will be an available option, but on Android 2.3 and lower devices, it will not.

Comment: Thank you very very much..sorry for confusing terms, It's works perfect as i wanted to do. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is supported in 2.3 version for sure.It is supported from Api Level 1.And yes ListView is only possible with app widgets from api Level 11(3.0).

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)
   then hide your listview.
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, Listview in widget not support for android 2.3.  please review this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037207/android-listview-in-widget

Comment: @ParmarS yes right i didn't motice listview with widgets.Edited answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: I want to hide widget[widget-name] from widget's list.

Comment: in that case u have to create differently for version lower than api 11.